# Linear regression when a non-zero intercept is theoretically implausible

Tags: regression, intercept

How should I think of a linear model with a positive intercept when, theoretically, the intercept has to be zero?
Think of the following example: we are modeling how many birds does a feral cat hunt daily, predicted by the number of steps it has taken, the number of leaps, and the number of times it has extended its claws. Let’s say our model’s intercept is different from zero, and positive, yet we know that if the cat didn’t take a single step, leapt a single leap, nor extended its claws, it has certainly not caught any birds.
What does a non-zero intercept tell us in the case where it defies reason? Does this indicate that our model is inaccurate? Should we drop the intercept from our model?

Comment: You can require that the intercept be zero, both theoretically and in software. I don’t remember the R command, but even Excel allows that when you put in a trend line.

Comment: In your example, theory says the intercept is zero. But then, as the great statistician Yogi Berra may have said: “In theory, theory and practice are the same; in practice, they aren’t.” Personally, I would never force the intercept, even for Ohm’m law or Beer’s law, because the data might be revealing an issue.

Comment: Hi: Keep in mind that, if you do force it to be zero, then all the rsquared theory goes out the window because the decomposition of the sums of squares no longer holds. The fact that the decomposition doesn't hold is not  tragic  but definitely don't use the resulting rsquared to judge the model fit.

Answer (score 2):

As George Box said, "all models are wrong, but some are useful". If you've built the model described above you were presumably interested in modeling cats that have typical hunting patterns. Your theoretical cat is probably too far from the actual data to accurately predict. If most cats take 10k-20k steps (a complete guess) then extrapolating to 0 is quite far and I would question the result. If the model fits the actual data well then I wouldn't worry about these theoretical cats. If you *are* concerned with immobile cats, find more samples filling in the gaps down to zero. you may find that a linear fit is not appropriate as these new data are added.

Answer (score 0):

> How should I think of a linear model with a positive intercept when, theoretically, the intercept has to be zero?

Computers will estimate whatever we ask of them, regardless of if it makes sense or not.  By letting the intercept be a parameter, you are saying that *you don't know* how many birds the cat will have hunted given its steps, and so you want to estimate it. The model will return an estimate of exactly 0 with probability 0, so relying on the model (or the computer) to make important decisions is clearly a bad idea.

> What does a non-zero intercept tell us in the case where it defies reason?

It tells is that we need to rethink what we are trying to model; that we have misinterpreted something along the way and we need to go back and rectify it.